# How do I configure AWS CLI on Windows 10

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have configured AWS CLI on Windows 10.

But when I run the `aws s3 ls` command I am getting below error.

Can anyone tell me about the problem?

```
C:\Users\admin>aws s3 ls
Failed to connect to proxy URL: "https://127.0.0.1:8080"
```

Comment: Do you use any proxy programs such as Fiddler? close all current processes and try again

Comment: Yeah I'm using burpsuite. Even after I close Burpsuite the problem still exists @AmitBaranes.

Comment: It could be a ghost process, Restart will solve it 100%.
Take a look at this thread for more info :https://superuser.com/questions/1238840/how-to-remove-a-proxy-virus-127-0-0-18080-from-windows-10

Comment: Do you have a proxy set? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-proxy.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing Fiddler application solved the issue.
If you are using fiddler application or some debugging proxy server. Try closing the applicaiton and try again.